# Changing a date into a checkbox in Django

Tags: python, django, date, checkbox

I have a customer table that has an id, name, telephone and a date where the customer was set to inactive (called 'inactive_date').

In my form, I only want a checkbox to appear.  If there is a date, then the checkbox is set.  If the date is empty, then the checkbox is not set.

The only way I can set the checkbox so far is by doing the following:

```
class MyCustomerForm(ModelForm):
     inactive_checkbox = forms.BooleanField(initial='checked')
```

I tried to use a clean or an init method to be able to set the checkbox based on a condition, but these attempts down below have been unsuccessful.  My form always return the checkbox as unset regardless of the contents of the inactive_date.

```
class MyCustomerForm(ModelForm):
     inactive_checkbox = forms.BooleanField()
     def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
         inactive_date = self.cleaned_data['inactive_date']
         if (inactive_date != None):
             self.fields['inactive_checkbox'] = 'checked'
         return self.cleaned_data

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(myCustomerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        inactive_date = self.cleaned_data['inactive_date']
        if (inactive_date != None):
             self.fields['inactive_checkbox'] = 'checked'

class Meta:
    model = MyCustomer
    fields = ['customer_id','customer_name','customer_phone',
              'inactive_checkbox']
```

Any idea what is wrong with my code or is there perhaps a better way to control my inactive_date through a checkbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with initial:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values

In your view check the state of inactive_date field and then pass the result to the form via initial argument.

Hope it can help.

Comment: Thank you!  Your answer was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Create a new widget with the desired behavior. The default CheckboxInput widget (tested in django 3.2) properly checks or unchecks the checkbox based on if the field is a datetime or None. Then, you just override the response returned from user input:

```py
from django.forms.widgets import CheckboxInput
from django.utils import timezone


class DateTimeCheckboxInput(CheckboxInput):
    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        # cast the boolean returned to a timestamp or None
        value = super().value_from_datadict(data, files, name)
        return timezone.now() if value else None
```

Then, you can use this widget in any django model form

```
class MyCustomerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyCustomer
        fields = ['inactive_checkbox']
        widgets = {
            "inactive_checkbox": widgets.DateTimeCheckboxInput,
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post my new form based on jorlugaqui's answer as a comment, but comments are very limited in terms of formatting and length.

So here's my new form and view based on jorlugaqui's recommendation:

New form:

```
class MyCustomerForm(ModelForm):
    inactive_checkbox = forms.BooleanField(required=False, label="Inactive")

    class Meta:
        model = MyCustomer
        fields = ['customer_id','customer_name','customer_phone']
```

New view:

```
def customer_detail(request):
    id = request.GET.get('id')
    item = MyCustomer.objects.get(customer_id=id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyCustomerForm(request.POST, instance=item, initial={'inactive_checkbox': item.inactive})
        if form.is_valid():
            inactive = request.POST.get('inactive_checkbox')
            modified_item = form.save(commit=False)
            if inactive:
                if modified_item.inactive == None:
                    modified_item.inactive = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            else:
                modified_item.inactive = None
            modified_item.save()
    else:
        form = MyCustomerForm(initial={'inactive_checkbox': item.inactive}, instance=item)
    return render(request, 'basic_detail.html', {'id': id, 'form': form})
```